# Make splice or unshift return the modified array

Tags: javascript, function

I am recently getting accustomed to the idea of chaining the function calls and it is making my life a lot easier. But the inbuilt Array functions of JavaScript don't seem too cooperative.

How to make `unshift` or `splice` return the modified rather than the length of array and deleted items respectively? I am assuming there is a way to this with some tricky calls to `call` or `apply`.

I had to go out of my way and use `concat` for my use case, is there a better way of doing it?

```
Eg: 
 a = [2,3,4,5]
 one solution : somethingElse([1].concat(a))
 I wanted to do something like:  somethingElse(a.unshift(1));
 or may be like this: somethingElse(a.splice(0,0,1));
```

Comment: `call` and `apply` can change the way the functions are called, they cannot change the return values of the functions.

Comment: Yeah, but I was wondering someway we can get this functionality. Its kind of sad that we cannot chain it like this for the power of functions like `splice` too good to loose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use grouping by parentheses, f.e. to return modified array after slice:

```
var a = [2,3,4,5];
somethingElse((a.splice(0,0,1), a));
```

Comment: This is a new concept for me. Can you elaborate or provide some link for this? Is this taking advantage of how comma operator works?

Comment: @sasidhar javascript interpreter just execute each instruction inside parentheses from left to right and returns the last one

Comment: simple and elegant solution. Thanks.

Comment: @sasidhar read [this](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/04/04/the-javascript-comma-operator/) for more

Answer (score 4):

One possible way is to override the original [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) methods in the following way:

```
var unshift = Array.prototype.unshift;
Array.prototype.unshift = function() {
    unshift.apply(this, arguments);
    return this;
};

[1, 2, 3].unshift(0);  // [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Besides it is rather **bad practice** and **you should avoid it**. Instead you can create your own prototype method with unique name and use it.

Comment: If you do choose this answer, you'll probably want to name it something like `prepend`, to not ruin other scripts in your page.